Hepburn romanization of "知りせば"
I have a question regarding romanization of the verb 知りせば, in Modified Hepburn Romanization System.
From what I know, 知りせば is a form of past tense of 知る, but is not used in modern japanese. せば would be functioning as conjunctive postpositional particle in ancient japanese grammar, but I want to know if in romanization it would be "shiriseba" or "shiri seba" with spacing, to give differentiation with old grammar which functions as postpositional particle, or modernized form which would be just tense changing of 知る, without spacing.
Thanks in advance !

In addition to what is said in rk03's answer, I mention that -k-eᵐba and -s-eᵐba are forms of Past Tense suffix -ki / -si with Conditional suffix -aᵐba (phonemically voiced obstruents were prenasalized in Old and Middle Japanese; see also here). Western linguists consider -aᵐba (modern -aba, archaic maybe except in words naraba, saraba) and another similar thing -ᵐba (modern -ba) to be suffixes, not any particles.

Another important note is that if you have seen 知りせば anywhere then probably in very old text, but Hepburn romanization scheme is designed to approximate phonetics of very recent Modern Japanese (20th / 21th century) into pseudo-English. Even at around 1850, syllable え was still [je] and may have been transcribed as "ye" in English (e.g. えど → "Yedo", えむ・えん → "yen"). For old historical texts, there are better romanization schemes.

First, there is no set way of romanization of Japanese language. Unfortunately, even discussions among styles (such as Hepburn and Kunrei-shiki) are mostly about spelling of each sound, and not about spacing, hyphenation, or punctuation. (Sorry but I don’t know if there is any academic conventions.)
If you don’t have any guideline to follow, for reference, I show you one made in 1952 by 国語審議会, though it was written aiming to regulate spacing in romanization of modern language.
https://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kakuki/01/bukai09/01.html
https://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kakuki/01/bukai09/02.html
https://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kakuki/01/bukai09/03.html
Overinterpreting the rules to your question, 知りせば would be “shiriseba” according to the rules 4-a and 5-e.
